# Which default logback properties file does Maven use?

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j, logback

When making a [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) build of my project with `install` I'm seeing log files such as the following ones when running tests:

```
07:29:43.616 [main] WARN  a.b.c.d.e.f.converter.DateConverter - Error during converting value
07:29:43.646 [main] DEBUG g.h.i.l.m.spring.ExecutorShutdown - Shutting down executor service
```

I'm sure that the first statement is print with an [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) logger. As other dependencies there are [logback-classic](http://logback.qos.ch/) with the scope `test` and [commons-logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) with the scope `compile` included.

I want to reduce the logging statements to the level `INFO`. From the formatting of the statements it looks like there's somewhere a `logback.xml` (or similiar) file. But I don't know of any.

How can I find out which logging properties file is used and how can I set the level to `INFO`?

Comment: If you ever need to examine the classpath of maven test, try adding -X to the execution. Although extremely verbose, you can for each plugin see the configuration and resolved classpath. Sometimes helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that [Logback uses](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration) the [BasicConfigurator](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/BasicConfigurator.html) if no file for configuration is found.